# TypeError: Cannot read property 'url0' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

[image]when i was running the code it was working fine and image is showing but after some time im getting this error.

```
<Card hoverable
           style={{ width:240 ,padding:3}}
          onClick={()=>this.moveToDest(item)}
          pose={this.state.hovering ? "hovered" : "idle"}
          onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({ hovering: true })}
          onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ hovering: false })}

          //  src={'http://192.168.0.103:5001/'+item.images.filename}
          cover={<img  alt="example" src={item.images.url0} style={{height:'180px'}} />}
          ><Card.Meta title={item.name} description={item.country} /></Card>
      </List.Item>
    )}
  />
```

image will be shown in the card

Comment: Where is your fetchDestinations function? The code is not a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: it means something is updating your state and it makes your item undefined

Comment: I think I might know. What about removing "height:180px"?

Comment: its worked i removed the style refresh then it worked.

Comment: So the problem should be in the `style={{ }}` element.

Comment: @zixuan yes . But now its working fine with style also.

Comment: @zixuan Why should there be a problem with the `style` prop? I can't see any connection between it and the error. The problem is that at some point `item.images` becomes `undefined`. We can't know why that happens with the code OP provided.

Comment: Yes, but he said it worked after the style element was removed.

Comment: Alright. That's why I said it wasn't a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @zixuan No he said that is works both with and without it. How do you relate that to the error message at all? It clearly says that `item.images` is `undefined` which is the cause for the error in the first place.

Comment: So get more of his code! Check where he set `item.images` to undefined (or deleted it).

Comment: @zixuan see i dont know what happend that time my code was working fine then after sometime its automatically giving errors thats why i also got confused what happened.  Then i tried like you said and it worked then i again put style in the tag and its worked again.

Comment: @ChandanJaiswal Strange behavior. Do you have a function that deletes the whole `item.images`? Because that caused the error.